# Unsure what this Zend helper bit of code is doing

Tags: zend-framework, helper

I cannot for the life of me figure out where the Register helper function is. I've grepped, I've gone through a bunch of code, I've gone through a bunch of Zend code, but can't find `Register()` anywhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public function registerAction()
{
  $this->_helper->Register();
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Zend action helper? Have you checked other directories within `Library` - `My`, `App` etc.?

Comment: Thank you @bububaba for that suggestion. I found something in `Library` that matches. (Sorry, new to ZendFr.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not ZF's action helper. Look in your libraries folder in subdirectories like `*_Controller_Action_Helper` where * means your libraries like bububa said in his comment (My_, App_, ...)